# how to search for exact string in mysql

Tags: mysql, collation, case-sensitive

I'm trying to search for an exact match of a string in mysql. The string is 'nrew'. But when I do the queries below, I still get a result:

```
SELECT UserID FROM sys_users WHERE UserID='NREW'
SELECT UserID FROM sys_users WHERE UserID='NrEw'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID FROM sys_users WHERE BINARY UserID='NREW'
```

Comment: As an additional note, if you are matching on unique user accounts names, make sure you use BINARY too as otherwise, names like aimé.smith and aime.smith are assumed to be the same value regardless of the special character difference.

Answer (score 9):

The default collation which MySQL uses to make comparisons is case insensitive. You need to specify a case sensitive collation or binary. You can either do this when creating the column, or in the query.

For example:

```
SELECT UserID FROM sys_users WHERE UserID='NREW' COLLATE latin1_bin
```

The proper collation depends on your character set. For `latin1`, the default, you can use `latin1_bin`. For `utf8`, `utf8_bin`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use keyword Binary,

```
SELECT UserID FROM sys_users WHERE BINARY UserID='nrew'
```

refer to [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html)

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use `LIKE BINARY` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT UserID FROM sys_users WHERE UserID LIKE BINARY 'nrew';
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this is try: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13043

```
Select UserID from sys_users where convert(varbinary, UserID) = convert(varbinary, 'NREW')
```

Or try COLLATE

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/09/30/Case-Sensitive-or-Insensitive-SQL-Query.aspx