# Select count(*) returns a row even when I dont expect it

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So I am querying a MySql database from my java application and I am trying to use a query,

```
Select count(*) from table where `NUMERIC`='1'
```

to count the rows from a database. When I run this query it works fine, and I get a 1 returned (I am using a test db with 12 records, `Numeric` has values 1-12 so this makes sense). However I wanted to try to break this and do some error handling. I changed my query to

```
Select count(*) from table where `Numeric`='1adjfa'
```

I expected this to return 0, however it still returns 1. In fact, as long as I have 1 at the beginning of the value it will work, if I change the value to just 'adjfa' than it returns 0. I have confirmed this through both my Java App and the MySQL workbench. Any ideas as to why this returns 1, even with the junk at the end of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to search for exact string in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632598/how-to-search-for-exact-string-in-mysql)

Comment: What is column type of `Numeric` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two different data types can *not* be compared.  Instead one of the two needs to be cast/coerced to the same data type as the other.

In your case you're not doing the coercion, so the DB Engine is doing an *implicit* coercion.

Based on data-type-order-of-precedence, the database engine chooses the string to be coerced to a numeric.

The value `'1adjfa'` therefore becomes a `1`, and ***then*** your comparison is being made.

This results is your query effectively being:

```
Select count(*) from table where `Numeric` = 1
```

You should either not be comparing numerics and strings, or do the coercion yourself, for example...

```
Select count(*) from table where CAST(`Numeric` AS VARCHAR(32)) = '1adjfa'
```

In terms of breaking the query, I'm hoping that in your application you're actually using *parameterised queries*.  This will allow you to define the data-type of the parameter, and your application should throw the error if the wrong data-type is supplied.

Comment: Additional note:  This is because `CAST('1adjfa' AS NUMERIC)` = `1`

Answer (score 3):

`Numeric` has a number data type. To make the comparision to `1adjfa` the DB engine tries to convert it also to a number which results in `1` and the rest gets cut off.