# CodeIgniter sometimes got message query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

Although its rare to happen, but sometimes my project will showing error message in my query.

I think this happend not because of my query.

Any suggestion why this can happen?

This is the example of my query.

```
select * from (
        select rlog.id_issue, created.LogUser as create_by, created.LogTime as create_time,r_change.change_by,rlog.tglupt,
        r_aprove.date1 as aproved_date,issue_type,nama_app,status,kondisi,logAct, r_issue.keterangan, logket, param
        from (select id_issue, logAct, max(logtime) as tglupt,param, logket from r_log group by id_issue, logAct, logket,param) rlog
        inner join (select Id_issue, LogUser, LogTime from r_log where LogAct like 'add%' ) created on rlog.id_issue = created.id_issue
        left join r_change on rlog.id_issue = r_change.id_issue
        left join r_aprove on r_change.id_change = r_aprove.id_change
        left join r_issue on rlog.id_issue = r_issue.id_issue
        inner join r_app_det on r_issue.id_app = r_app_det.id_app
        )z where issue_type is not null
        and id_issue = ".$id."
        order by tglupt, case when logAct = 'Add' then '1' else logact end asc
```

this is my data for `$query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mUser WHERE username='".$uname."'");` :

```
-----------------------------------------
  username   |     name        |  role
-----------------------------------------
    ADR      |     andry       |    2
    AND      |     Andrew      |    4
 ------------------------------------------
```

-sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: post the error message

Comment: @barcelona_delpy thats the problem, when i refresh the page, the error is gone and my project run normal. its very rare that wrong message will show. if the error show, i will post it.

Comment: @barcelona_delpy this the error what i got: Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myproject\application\models\query.php on line 88. line always change. thats why im so confuse, whats wrong with my project.

Comment: im suspecting the problem is on my connection, can that be posible because of connection? ex: server RunTimeError.

Comment: Put your line no 88 from `query.php`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam this 87 and 88 : [87]$query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mUser WHERE username='".$uname."'");
[88]if($query->row()){

Comment: Edit code to include on how  are u fetching $uname variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is on my connection, i try it on localhost and never have the problem. thx all.

Answer (score 0):

For some $uname you doesn't get any result. So you should check query returns the result or not before you convert into row(). Like this

```
$query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mUser WHERE username='".$uname."'"); 
if($query->num_rows() == 1){
    $query->row();
}else{
 //....
}
```

Comment: then what cause $uname doesnt  get any result ? when another time it have result.

Comment: can you post sample data of uname and DB contains username column values. because there may be mis-match character. So please post here sample data

Comment: there username "ADR" in capital letters. Suppose if you give "adr"(small letters) OR "Adr" and so on, it will not match. So you should check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632598/how-to-search-for-exact-string-in-mysql

Comment: i thing thats not the real problem here. thanks btw.

Comment: ok. just execute by different string like this in Command SELECT * FROM mUser WHERE username='ADR' //
    SELECT * FROM mUser WHERE username='adr' //
    SELECT * FROM mUser WHERE username='Adr'

Comment: i try all u suggest and there is no different in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using.
$query->row(); OR $query->result(); in the end of query.

```
$query =$this->db->query("select * from (
        select rlog.id_issue, created.LogUser as create_by, created.LogTime as create_time,r_change.change_by,rlog.tglupt,
        r_aprove.date1 as aproved_date,issue_type,nama_app,status,kondisi,logAct, r_issue.keterangan, logket, param
        from (select id_issue, logAct, max(logtime) as tglupt,param, logket from r_log group by id_issue, logAct, logket,param) rlog
        inner join (select Id_issue, LogUser, LogTime from r_log where LogAct like 'add%' ) created on rlog.id_issue = created.id_issue
        left join r_change on rlog.id_issue = r_change.id_issue
        left join r_aprove on r_change.id_change = r_aprove.id_change
        left join r_issue on rlog.id_issue = r_issue.id_issue
        inner join r_app_det on r_issue.id_app = r_app_det.id_app
        )z where issue_type is not null
        and id_issue = ".$id."
        order by tglupt, case when logAct = 'Add' then '1' else logact end asc");
 foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: ofcourse i have $query->result() in the end of query